# How to insert values into an SQL view which has columns from multiple tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-view

I have an SQL view created by joining columns of two separate tables.

I need to know how to insert a record into this view.

Here's the code I tried,

```
create view P_Order
as
select Product.Pname, Product.Pdesc, Product.Pprice, Order1.Onumber, Order1.Oqty
from Product
join Order1
on Order1.Procode=Product.Pcode;

select * from P_Order;

insert into P_Order (Pname, Pdesc, Pprice, Onumber, Oqty) values('Toshiba','Television',48000.00,10023,25);
```

It generated an error saying,

```
View or function 'P_Order' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Take a peek at https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=130855&seqNum=4  Pay special attention to the restrictions.

Comment: you doesn't have any join with your 2 table product and order ? :o i think you have missing some join like product.product_id = order.product_id ?

Comment: Your query is wrong. It doesn't match products and orders, it combines *every* product with *every* order. For 10 products with 100 orders, you'd get back 1000 rows

Comment: Why are you trying to insert into the *view* in the first place? Are you really trying to create a *new* Toshiba TV record each time you place an order? Or are you trying to avoid looking up the product when inserting an order ?

Comment: @Sanpas ah, of couse!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edited my code with a join. But the error is same.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti so it is not possible?

Comment: You didn't explain what you want to do yet. That INSERT attempt doesn't make sense. Do you *really* want to add duplicate rows in `Products`? Because that's what that query attempts to do. Instead of guessing what you want (which even a human can't do), the server simply refuses to execute the command

Comment: @KushaniSasiprabha Nope, not with this scenario.  Just seems wiser to insert into your orders table.  I'm assuming your product table is unique and definitive.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I guess the intention of the question given to me was just to test my knowledge on inserting records into views. There's nothing other than that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting Records into a `VIEW` with two table in Join Condition in not advisable it leads to multiple changes in the both tables.

So Instead of inserting them into the View, you can insert the records into separate tables.